# groupby by the column, pandas

Tags: python, jupyter

How to calculate mean value from second column with object which are groupby for first column?

```
    area    sallary
1    life     3500
2    life     3800
3    science  5000
4    other    4000
5    science  3000
6    other    5000

mean_life = 3650
mean_science = 4000
mean_other = 4500
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
df.groupby('area').mean()

         sallary
area            
life        3650
other       4500
science     4000
```

Comment: Thank you. Shame for me, that was easy. My first steps in programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following code:

```
df.groupby(['area']).mean()
```

Comment: Thank you. Shame for me, that was easy. My first steps in programming.

Comment: Never easy if you haven't tried it before :) Good luck!